# Is redirecting to HTTP URL from a HTTPS POST possible?

Tags: php, apache, http

In my application I am setting the `Location` header to `http://www.foo.com` inside a route that responds to a POST request over HTTPS. I keep getting redirected to `https://www.foo.com` instead of the plain HTTP version. If you handle a POST over HTTPS will all redirects be forced over HTTPS as well?

This is on an Apache server running PHP 5.3.

Comment: Is it possible your vHost configuration is forcing port 80 to 443?